# How to adjust the distance of one 3D point from another 3D point by a given distance

Tags: c#, math, vector, point

I am working with point3D and vector3D classes and I need some help adjusting a point by a given distance.

- Point A  - point residing at coordinate 0,0,0.
- Point B  - point residing at coordinate 1,1,1.
- Vector AB - vector AB which tells me the length between the two points A and B is distance = 1.73205078.

[image]

Code:

```
Point3D A = new Point3D { X = 0, Y = 0, Z = 0 };
Point3D B = new Point3D { X = 1, Y = 1, Z = 1 };
Vector3D AtoB = A - B;
Double distanceBetweenAandB = AtoB.Length; // the distance will be 1.73205078 here.
```

I would like to adjust point B.  I would like to reduce the distance between point A and point B to 0.5 instead of 1 (adjusting to position C as shown in the diagram).  I am trying to work out how to do this.

Point A (0,0,0) is known, point B (1,1,1) is known and the distance to adjust by is known (0.5).  How do I calculate?

Pseudo code:

```
Point3D A = new Point3D { X = 0, Y = 0, Z = 0 };
Point3D B = new Point3D { X = 1, Y = 1, Z = 1 };
Double distanceToAdjust = 0.5;

Point3D newCoordinate = B - distanceToAdjust; // this doesnt work!
```

Adjusted point B shown in diagram below:

[image]

I am using my own defined Point3D class and Vector3D class.

Comment: The length of vector `[1 1 1]` is not 1, it is `SQRT(3) = 1.732(...)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In pseudo code, here's how I ended up implementing

```
pointA = …
pointB = …
vectorAB = B-A
desiredDistance = 0.5;  // where 0.5 is vectorAB.Length/desiredDistance
vectorAC = vectorAB * desiredDistance ; 

pointC = A+vectorAC;
```

Actual code:

```
Vector3D pointC = (Vector3D)(A + (float)desiredDistance  * (B - A));
```

Answer (score 5):

Let's assume your given parameters for your points, and create a 3rd, which we'll call `newCoordinate`, and that point `A` will be your reference:

```
Point3D A = new Point3D { X = 0, Y = 0, Z = 0 };
Point3D B = new Point3D { X = 1, Y = 1, Z = 1 };

Double distanceToAdjust = 0.5;

Point3D newCoordinate = new Point3D { 
                                        A.X + ((B.X - A.X) * distanceToAdjust),
                                        A.Y + ((B.Y - A.Y) * distanceToAdjust),
                                        A.Z + ((B.Z - A.Z) * distanceToAdjust)
                                    }
```

Here we see the original points:

[image: Original plotted points]

Assuming this values, `newCoordinate` would sit at X=0.5, Y=0.5, Z=0.5. Nice graph follows:

[image]

There it is, sitting right in between the two original points.

As a simulation, if you change A and B and assume this values instead:

```
Point3D A = new Point3D { X = -8, Y = 4, Z = 3 };
Point3D B = new Point3D { X = 3, Y = 2, Z = 1 };
```

Then `newCoordinate` position would be X=-2.5, Y=3, Z=2.

[image]

Now, same points, but using `distanceToAdjust  = 1.2`:

[image]

Keep this two things in mind:

- Changes in distance always need a reference point. In my sample, I assumed A; that's why it appears as the first portion of each `newCoordinate` parameter initialization.
- distanceToAdjust was taken as a *multiplier factor*.

Addendum: The nifty tool I used to help visualization [can be found here](http://hotmath.com/learning_activities/interactivities/3dplotter.swf).

Answer (score 4):

Assuming you implemented vector operations:

if point A is always [0,0,0]

```
Point3D new = B.Normalize() * distance;
```

for any two points

```
Point3D newCoord = A + ((B - A).Normalize() * distance); //move to origin, normalize, scale and move back
```

not fast solution though.

Answer (score 3):

> "the length between the two points A and B is distance = 1"

No, the distance is the square root of three, about 1.732.

The distance from (0,0,0) to (0,0,1) is 1. The distance from (0,0,0) to (0,1,1) is the square root of two. (Think a triangle in two dimensions, and Pythagoas theorem.) The distance from (0,0,0) to (1,1,1) is the square root of three. (Think a triangle in two dimensions, where that dimension is on a plane along the hypothenuse of the previous triangle. AB = √(1² + (√2)²).)

---

I assume that you don't want to subtract 0.5 from anything, but actually multiply the distance by 0.5, i.e. getting halfways from A to B. You can calculate the point C by taking that part of the distance between point A and point B in each dimension:

```
Point3D C = new Point3D {
  A.X + (B.X - A.X) * distanceToAdjust,
  A.Y + (B.Y - A.Y) * distanceToAdjust,
  A.Z + (B.Z - A.Z) * distanceToAdjust
};
```

Comment: um... it's not 2, it's the square root of 3. `|V| = sqrt(x^2 + y^2 + z^2)`

Comment: I must say that @J... is spot-on.

Comment: Blame it on lack of coffee, @Guffa. That's what I do. ;)

Comment: As commented in OnoSendai's answer, you have to define a common reference point for all the calculations; otherwise your outputs are random. For example, it seems like the OP wants to rely on the smallest coordinates and thus you should perform this pre-check; otherwise your algorithm would output different results depending upon the order of the input points. I hope that you understand this idea (too tired to re-explain more).

Comment: @varocarbas: I can't see that commend, and I don't really get what you are getting at. The code creates a point that is somewhere on a line from A to B, depending on the `distanceToAdjust` value. If you don't know if you are going from A to B, or from B to A, then the output is really random. Besides, if you would want to go from the smallest coordinates, then you would have to start by defining what you mean by "smallest".

Comment: What I mean is clearly explained in the OnoSendai's comments (deleted by moderation reasons...): With the OP's inputs his code (and your code) delivers 0.5,0.5,0.5. If you change the order of the inputs (B instead of A and vice versa), you would get 1.5,1.5,1.5. What I said (what was present in my answer, now deleted) was: take ALWAYS the same reference points (smaller ones; because the OP's wants something within the projection of the line, not beyond) and thus you would ALWAYS get the same result with the same input coordinates, independently upon its order (what your code does not deliver).

Comment: Two further clarifications: with smallest I meant minimum value per coordinate (my answer was like yours but: minX + (...), minY + (...), minZ + (...); where minX is the minimum value out of Ax and Bx, minY is minimum value out of Ay and By, etc.); alternatively might be maxX, maxY, etc. but your code ignores that and takes min/max randomly (= random approach). Second clarification: I cannot continue this discussion because a while ago I promised to a moderator to stop doing this kind of things (commenting) :) I hope that my ideas are clear enough (refer to my comments above otherwise).

Comment: *"If you change the order of the inputs (B instead of A and vice versa), you would get 1.5,1.5,1.5"*. No, you are mistaken. The result of `0 + (1 - 0) * 0.5` is the same as `1 + (0 - 1) * 0.5`. It's impossible to get to (1.5,1.5,1.5) by interpolating between (0,0,0) and (1,1,1), regardless of the order of the input. Anyhow, getting the same value regardless of the order of the input makes no sense at all. Further more, if you start mixing minimum and maximum values between the coordinates, then you get random results, as you may end up with a point that is not even on the line from A to B.

Comment: I do believe varocarbas is referring to a previous version of my post where I simulated point A at {2,2,2} for demonstration purposes while keeping B at {1,1,1}, thus resulting in a interpolated {1.5,1.5,1.5} position, @Guffa.

Comment: @Guffa, your assessment is likewise corrrect. It seems that that bit was ignored.

Answer (score 0):

I'm unsure if this is what you would need but is it possible to create a method within your Point3D class to allow subtraction/addition?

(Just guessing the Point3D class as simply as it could be)Something like

```
   public class Point3D
   {

       public double X,Y,Z

       public void ChangeCord(Point3D point)
       {
           X =- point.X;
           Y =- point.Y;
           Z =- point.Z;
       }
   }
```

So it could just be:

```
    Point3D A = new Point3D { X = 0, Y = 0, Z = 0 };
    Point3D B = new Point3D { X = 1, Y = 1, Z = 1 };
    Double distanceToAdjust = 0.5;

    Point3D newCoordinate = B.ChangeCord(new Point3d{ X = 0.5, Y = 0.5, Z = 0.5 });
```